# Discord JS: Не могу изменить имя бота

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord-api

Хочу сделать, чтобы бот менял свой ник. Подскажите как правильно это сделать

```js
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const bot = new Discord.Client();
bot.on('ready', function() {
    bot.user.setUsername("Name");
})
bot.login('XXX');
```

В консоль пишет: Слишком быстро меняете ник, попробуйте позже

```html
(node:1788) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: DiscordAPIError: Invalid Form Body username: You are changing your username or Discord Tag too fast. Try again
later.
```

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй вот так залогировать все.
`bot.on('ready', async () =>{
const response = await bot.user.setUsername("Name").catch(e=>console.log(e.message));
console.log(response);
})
bot.login('XXX').then(console.log).catch(e=>console.log(e.message));`

P.s.: Прости за оформление, пишу с тлф

Comment: Я понял давно ошибку. В дело том, что я пытаюсь изменить имя бота, которое изменить нельзя. Можно только изменить имя бота на сервере. 
`message.guild.members.get(bot.user.id).setNickname("Ник");`